# Qual a diferença entre .cer, .pfx e .pvk?

Tags: segurança, ssl, certificado-digital, tls

Estava mexendo com alguns arquivos que são certificados digitais e certificados de segurança, então me surgiu a dúvida:

#### Qual a diferença entre um arquivo ***.cer***, ***.pfx*** e ***.pvk***?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segue essa resposta traduzida de uma outra pergunta realizada no [SO<sup>en</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292495/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cer-pvk-and-pfx-file:):

## Qual é a diferença entre um arquivo cer, pvk e pfx?

> O Windows usa a extensão *.cer* para um certificado X.509. Estes podem
>   ser em "binário" (*ASN.1 DER*), ou pode ser codificado com *Base-64* e ter
>   um cabeçalho e rodapé aplicado (*PEM*). O Windows reconhecerá também.
>   Para verificar a integridade de um certificado, você deve verificar
>   sua assinatura usando a chave pública do emissor ... que é, por sua
>   vez, outro certificado.
>
> O Windows usa *.pfx* para um arquivo *PKCS #12*. Esse arquivo pode conter
>   uma variedade de informações criptográficas, incluindo certificados,
>   cadeias de certificados, certificados de autoridade raiz e chaves
>   particulares. Seu conteúdo pode ser protegido criptograficamente (com
>   senhas) para manter as chaves privadas privadas e preservar a
>   integridade dos certificados raiz.
>
> O Windows usa *.pvk* para um arquivo de chave particular. Eu não tenho
>   certeza que padrão (se houver) o Windows segue para estes. Esperamos que
>   sejam chaves *PKCS #8* codificadas.
>
> Você nunca deve revelar sua chave privada. Esses estão contidos em
>   arquivos *.pfx* e *.pvk*.
>
> Geralmente, você só troca seu certificado (*.cer*) e os certificados de
>   quaisquer emissores intermediários (ou seja, os certificados de todas
>   as suas *CA's*, exceto a *CA* raiz) com outras partes.